# How long does it take to play Cuba?

Tags: cuba

How long does it take to play [Cuba](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/30380/cuba)? And does the playing vary considerably between different numbers of players?

Answer (score 3):

The time does depend on # of players, as turns are sequential, yet total rounds is fairly constant.  I would say 30 minutes per player is a good average.  The game will change significantly with # of players, as it makes use of several first-come mechanics (limited board resource slots) and, of course, the voting mechanic.   4-5 players will be the closest in game-play.